# how to get differnt coloumn record without while loop

Tags: php, mysql

my query is giving me  3 rows  record

```
SELECT * FROM `category` ORDER by id ASC limit 3
```

now my record contain column  with 3 diff values

```
     **cat_title**
       Abuse 
       Addiction
       ADCH
```

I want these three different values in my html code but

```
    while($row = $popData->fetch_assoc())
```

is giving me first value every time

Comment: is my question is unclear strange there is no response

Comment: Your php lacks the part where you **USE**  $row so how can we even offer an opinion on why it isn't working.  The question appears to be incomplete. And there just has to be a billion or more examples of looping through a sql result for output. So it may also appear you haven't researched for a solution.